# Google Map API Demo won't run unless you update Google Play services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm facing a problem when i run my emulator in android studio. The emulator prompt me **"Google Map API Demo won't run unless you update Google Play services"**.

I see this error message:

```
--------- beginning of crash 02-03 13:29:47.762 2870-2870/com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo, PID: 2870
                                                                                      android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms&pcampaignid=gcore_9683000--- flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1798)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 02-03 13:29:49.877 2870-2870/com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2870 SIG: 9 02-03 13:35:13.441 5142-5142/com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo-1/lib/x86 02-03 13:35:13.504 5142-5142/com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful 02-03 13:35:13.713 5142-5142/com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9683000 but found 9452470 02-03 13:35:13.726 5142-5142/com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo ... 5142-5261/com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

My build.gradle file is like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxx_000.googlemapapidemo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Comment: try it in real device it work. your emulator does not have play services install

Comment: Oh okay.. I will try with a real device. Thank you so much!

Comment: and it will work on devices which has play service install and same or higher version of 9.6,1

Comment: Oh okay, i will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your emulators and create one with an API level which says `(with Google APIs)` or use a real device.

Comment: Yup. They may well be up to date anyway, but it's worth checking before creating a new one.

Comment: I checked my sdk manager, and everything is updated. So i click on play and click on "Create New Emulator" to create a new one with an API level which says (with Google APIs)? I don't see one.

Comment: Oh, i think i know how. Click on Android Virtual Device Manager and i will see one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer will work for an emulator, this could be a real issue on a real device and this solution will not work on a real device. This could happen on an old device that has an outdated version of Google Play Services.

To overcome this issue, the Google Play Services library has a set of APIs to check the availability of Google Play Services, mainly the [`GoogleApiAvailability`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) class provides a few methods to handle availability issues such as an outdated version.

Now, to detect whether a device has Google Play Services available or not, what I normally do is create a helper method to run the check

```
private boolean checkPlayServices(){
    GoogleApiAvailability gaa = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = gaa.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        if(gaa.isUserResolvableError(result)){
            gaa.getErrorDialog(this,result, REQUEST_PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION).show();
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This helper method checks whether Google Play Services is available or not by inspecting the error code returned from `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`. Then it calls `isUserResolvableError` to determine if the error is resolvable by the user (e.g. by updating Google Play Services). If it is resolvable, then a dialog is displayed for the user to confirm he wants the system to resolve the error. Then call it on the Activity's `onCreate` method, I run that check as below

```
//I normally assume Google Play services is available
private boolean playServicesAvailable = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_selector);

    //check for rare case where Google Play Services is not available
    playServicesAvailable = checkPlayServices();

    if(!playServicesAvailable){
        //hide UI elements and turn off features that rely on Google Play Services
    }
}
```

Hope it helps some out there